# Ansible dynamic inventory when connecting with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I have downloaded ec2.py and ec2.ini files and placed them under

```
/etc/ansible/inventory
```

and i have changed the ansible.cfg to

```
inventory      = /etc/ansible/inventory/ec2.py
```

i have environment variables set up as

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-east-1"
export EC2_INI_PATH="/etc/ansible/inventory/ec2.ini"
```

now when i run ansible -m ping all
i am getting

```
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available
```

instead of pinging all instances in my account

when i run ./ec2.py --list i get

```
{
   "_meta": {
   "hostvars": {}
}
}
```

all my instances in aws are running

Comment: Did you try `ec2.py --refresh-cache`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are not using the right inventory file.

- Check ec2.py is executable (chmod +x)
- Run ansible with -v option to check what config file it is really
  using

  `ansible -v -m ping all`
- Check if you have ANSIBLE_INVENTORY or ANSIBLE_HOSTS environment
  variables overriding expected config file. You can override inventory definition by setting

  `export ANSIBLE_INVENTORY=/etc/ansible/inventory/ec2.py`

Remind that configuration files are processed in the following order

- ANSIBLE_CONFIG (an environment variable)
- ansible.cfg (in the current directory)
- .ansible.cfg (in the home directory)
- /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

Prior to 1.5 the order was:

- ansible.cfg (in the current directory)
- ANSIBLE_CONFIG (an environment variable)
- .ansible.cfg (in the home directory)
- /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

Comment: Thanks, i re-checked the config. with your suggestions it worked